# Edit AJAX response before made into json object

Tags: jquery, json

Is it possible to edit the response of an AJAX cross-domain request before it is made into an object? I have a malformed response (Which is not easily changed - large corporate structure *roll eyes*) and I need to get the data ASAP.

I have tried setting up a prefilter and a converter, to no avail.

```
$.ajax({ 
  url:url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR); console.log(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: You may find this useful : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093003/using-jquery-to-alter-an-ajax-response/24549419#24549419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JSONP you can't intercept and change data you receive. Consider it as a JS external resource that inject JS object directly to a function you specify, you have no way to change the incomming structure.

Comment: So there is no way at all to see the response text before it is converted to an object? Could I create my own XHttpRequest and send it manually?

Comment: If you don't need XDomain access, you can of course use an XHR, that will provide you plain-text, and transform/parse-it manually.

Comment: So when doing a JSONP request, the JSON is not being parsed by jQuery?

Comment: jQuery only add a <script src=[url to jsonp]></script> on the document, then your browser interpret that script (as every script included that way), not jQuery.

Comment: Jonny, correct. The string has an issue in it, and if I could intercept that string before it is assigned to an object, it would be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
  dataType: 'text'
```

and then You'll receive simple data in

```
  success( data ){
    // remark that data str as You wish
  }
```

Comment: dataType needs to be json or jsonp because it is a cross-domain request.