# Change value of input in XHR request with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm currently developing an webextension for Chrome and Fiferox. I'm loading some Html content using a get request and I need to change one of the inputs values in the HTML data response before insert in the DOM.

Here is a part of the relevant code:

```
var url = browser.extension.getURL("resources/forms/form-a.html");
$.get(url, function(data){

 $(data).find("input[id='name:front']").val("New Value");

 //Here the console output is NOT "New Value"
 console.log($(data).find("input[id='name:front']").val())

 $("#form-names").replaceWith($(data));

});
```

I hoping to change some inputs values before replacing the DOM content. 
Some ideas ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Here is a part of the relevant code` - is this your webextension?

Comment: no really, my webextension do a lot of other things but my question is how I can change the input value for replace the HTML content of the page. Need more info ?

Comment: so, that code is not part of the webextension? (I'm trying to get a handle on what you're asking)

Comment: yes, that code is in the content script of my webextension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `$(data)` you are parsing the response and creating new HTML elements ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)). If you saved the elements, changed the value, then updated your DOM you'll find it works OK.

```
var url = browser.extension.getURL("resources/forms/form-a.html");
$.get(url, function(data){

  var newForm = $(data);
  newForm.find("#name:front").val("New Value");

  // Here the console output is should be "New Value"
  console.log(newForm.find("#name:front").val())

  $("#form-names").replaceWith(newForm);
});
```

Comment: I use a different approach describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093003/using-jquery-to-alter-an-ajax-response I will test your solution and give a feedback .. thanks